# Is there a way to know when an android UI change renders?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to write an Android app that shows the user a word for exactly 50ms. It's not a huge problem when the word get's sometimes shown a little bit longer or a little bit shorter but I want to know exactly how long it shows.

Does Android allow me to gather the information about when exactly the UI change renders so that I can calculate how long the word shows?

Comment: **Interesting** question.

Comment: What about a Thread with 50ms blocker? Otherwise do it in onDraw().

Comment: Draw commands are batched and sent to graphics pipeline, there is no internal method to detect exact screen updates. Best bet is the place where draw commands are dispatched i.e. `onDraw()` of a view.